# Handing hundreds of RDS mysql db at same time

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, supervisord

I have a database with around a million job records that are executed in a queue. Everyday, about 50 000 new jobs are created and executed. I start dozens of aws spot instances and jobs are executed with supervisor workers (6 at a time).

The total database connection is 260 at the same time and the rds mysql instance type is t2.medium. When there are no jobs to do or if jobs are not created yet, workers will exit after a few seconds and a a new workers will check again if jobs are available and so on.

I noticed that there is a major slowdown when they all connect at the same time i.e. A query can take 8 seconds instead of 20ms. Then as soon as all instances are connected to the DB, everything seems fine again. So the questions is, how do I handle this so that the database is always super fast?

Should I try to start the workers not at the same time and add random sleeps before workers exit?

Also since there is a lot of Read/Write operations, should I scale my database with load balancers and read repblicas?

Comment: MySQL is not the best for a job queue. Since you're on Amazon have you tried using [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/)?

Comment: Yes, SQS and batch seem like good options but too basic for what I need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slowdown is probably caused by the instance type that you are using. [T2 family instances are burstable](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t2/), which means that under sustained load for long periods of time, the CPU credits balance will drain and the instance will become slower.

You should definitely look to upgrade your instance type to another class (e.g. m5 family) so the instance's performance will be stable under sustained loads.

Comment: It seems like getting a better instance works but I need to get a m5.4xlarge. What I noticed: When all jobs are running and there are no todo jobs in the pipeline, the workers that don't execute jobs exit after a few seconds and another process start. So what I think is causing the issue is that since there are no jobs left to do in the pipeline, the workers exit and they all try to reconnect at the same time. So every 3 seconds they close, then reconnect so maybe it's too many reconnect for mysql since connection are cpu expensive. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not certain that opening new DB connections are expensive, but I would definitely try to reduce connection attempts, or, at least, introduce some jitter so idle workers don't try to all connect at the exact same time.